# HTML/JS - Product images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a product page which has a main product image and small thumbnail images below it. When the smaller thumbnails are clicked, I'd like the main product image to change to the selected image.

What if I wanted to have a larger version appear when the main product image is clicked? How would I deal with this? What is the best implementation? (graceful and valid)

If possible, I'd like it so that the main product image and thumbnails aren't downsized.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to downsize images in the browser you'll need to create individual images for the thumb, the main, and a zoom. There are several jQuery plugins that can do zooming, jqZoom comes to mind.